# Format operator removes line breaks

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

I have a text file like this:

File: **sample1.txt**

```
foo: {0}
bar: {1}
Hello {2}
```

I run the following commands:

```
$txt = gc Sample1.txt

$txt -f "bar","foo","world"
```

I got the output:

```
foo: bar bar: foo Hello world
```

Where did all the line breaks go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-Content automically breaks the file into an array by lines. Use the -Raw flag to keep it as single string:

```
$txt = gc Sample1.txt -Raw
$txt -f "bar","foo","world"
```

If you are stuck on PowerShell 2, the Raw parameter doesn't exist. You need to use the .NET File API:

```
$txt = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($(Convert-Path Sample1.txt))
$txt -f "bar","foo","world"
```

I've used `Convert-Path` because the .NET File API will default to resolving paths relative to the process's current directory, which is not the same as the current location in the path provider.

Comment: Any powershell 2 alternative?

Comment: @deostroll Not directly. You've got to use the .NET APIs. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the $OFS automatic variable to control the Output Field Separator.  In your example, the output field separator is a space, which is the default value for $OFS.  You can see that space if you look closely at your output.

If you set $OFS to new line, as follows:

```
$OFS = "`n"
```

Your output should have the line breaks in it.  This variable is useful in some other circumstances as well.

Comment: Definitely the most "correct" answer here, although I might go for `$OFS = [System.Environment]::NewLine`

Answer (score 0):

gc returns a String Array without any returns. You need to specify the return with `n .

```
PS:> "foo: {0}`nbar: {1}`nHello {2}" -f  "bar","foo","world"
foo: bar
bar: foo
Hello world
```

Comment: How? The string is coming from a file. It has all line breaks in it already...even `[string]::Format` fails...

Comment: Ok what is the alternative to `gc` then?

Comment: This will work for you.  (Get-Content sample1.txt -Raw) -f "bar","foo","world"